# How to summarize the contributions of co-authors where they advised at all stages of the study, but technically only stepped in at the writing stage

Tags: authorship, author-order

My conundrum is this. All my coauthors have provided advice from conception to completion, on the study itself, data analysis, write-up but *haven't actually done anything at those stages other than provide me with advice*. They have however, contributed critically to some parts of the writing. I have to complete a statement of authorship and am not sure how to accurately describe this. If I said:

"All authors contributed to conception of the study, data collection, and analysis."

This would be over-selling co-author contribution.

BUT, if I say:

"ABC conceived the study, collected the data, and conducted the analysis, all authors critically contributed to writing of the manuscript."

I am worried this undersells the input from others.

Is it better to over-sell, in this scenario?

Comment: If they didn't collect data, you could drop that, but isn't "contributed to conception of the study" accurate for people who gave advice from start to finish? That's exactly what contributes to the conception and design of a study.

Comment: Good point. What about analysis? If I am conducting all the analysis but they are advising, i.e. what tests to do, which variables to drop from a model (or whatever, made up examples), is this covered in "conception of the study"?

Comment: IMO, choosing the analysis methodology for most studies is the primary intellectual contribution to data analysis. Sometimes the actual necessary programming is quite time consuming, but that's not necessarily what counts for authorship.

Comment: This is an opinion based question, so I won't give a formal answer. But I think that you gain much by being generous in such matters. People outside your own circle won't be keeping score. People can contribute "equally" without contributing in the same way.

Comment: Who is ABC? You?

Answer (score 5):

> All my coauthors have provided advice from conception to completion, on the study itself, data analysis, write-up...If I said: "All authors contributed to conception of the study, data collection, and analysis." This would be over-selling co-author contribution.

I disagree. That's exactly what your co-authors did. Execution and writing needn't be the responsibility of all authors, especially when one author is a PhD student.

One way to better appreciate the efforts of others is to ask whether work could have been completed without their input. When the answer is *yes*, you could consider whether their efforts are worthy of acknowledgement rather than co-authorship. When the answer is *no*, it is surely clear they played an integral role and merit co-authorship.

Returning to the OP's example, you could ask: Could the study have been conceived without all authors? If so, then perhaps attribute conception to only those that were needed. Ask the same for data collection and analysis. You can then write a more accurate contribution statement. Personally, I'd be generous. Err on the side of inclusion.

Comment: Yes, "All authors contributed" != "All authors contributed equally," although I agree with the comments it's fine to break out data collection if the other authors didn't do it

Comment: Great. Thanks for your input! Makes sense.